# Grunt + Browserify + React cannot find called modules

Tags: reactjs, ubuntu-14.04, grunt-contrib-watch, grunt-browserify

I'm trying to set up a development server on Ubuntu 14 and am using Grunt + Browserify. I'm able to make the code run and if I use Grunt to watch for sass changes those work. However, any time I make a change to a react file that calls on another module I get an error like this:

> Error: Cannot find module '../../actions/mainActions' from '/var/www/p/web/sites/docroot/js/flux/app/components/pages'
>   Warning: Error running grunt-browserify.
>
> Fatal error: Callback was already called.

This works in an OS X environment and Windows environment, but not so far on Ubuntu.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

We figured out the issue, turns out since Linux is case-sensitive it was unable to find "mainActions" as the file itself was named "MainActions". Good overview on the topic: https://gist.github.com/domenic/2790533